# Is there a way to convert time logged as Minutes:Seconds into numeric form?

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that has time tracked as minutes:seconds (34:15 would be 34 minutes and 15 seconds) and its stored as a character currently. Is there a way to convert this to just minutes so that 34:15 would show up as 35.25?

Comment: `as.numeric(lubridate::ms("34:15"))/60`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions might include:

`time <- c("4:30","2:20","34:15")`

Base R:

```
c(as.matrix(read.table(text=time, sep=':')) %*% c(1,1/60))
[1]  4.500000  2.333333 34.250000
```

Lubridate:

```
 as.numeric(lubridate::ms(time))/60
 [1]  4.500000  2.333333 34.250000
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be split on the colon, convert to numeric, then divide the minutes by 60 to get the decimal.

```
time <- c("4:30","2:20","34:15")

sapply(strsplit(time,":"),
       function(x) {
         x <- as.numeric(x)
         x[1]+x[2]/60
       }
)

[1]  4.500000  2.333333 34.250000
```